# How to generate an Active Record query from an expresssion with logical operators and parantheses ? For ex: ((A || B) && C) || !D

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, activerecord, logical-operators, ruby-on-rails-6

I am going to implement a tag system that can be associated to a model (that I'm gonna call Car for the example) as a one to many association.

The project is using Rails 6.0 and ruby 2.7

So a **Car** has many **Tags**.

The final purpose of this tag system is to be able to filter out **Cars** with a logical expression using these tags. For example, you would put something like this in an input:

((red || blue) && sportcar) || !suv

Out of this, i want to generate an activerecord query selecting:

- all cars that are tagged with (*red* **or** *blue*) **and** tagged with *sportcart*
- **or** all cars that are **not** tagged with *suv* tag

Basically this requires to parse the logical expression with parentheses taken into account and then generate a query from the result of the parsing of this expression.

I'm wondering what are the best solutions to implement that. I guess that the parsing of an expression like this would result in a tree then i would need to parse that tree again an generate my query out of this.

But maybe there is a better solution I'm not seeing here so if anybody has an input on how to do that in a proper way I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled upon the [Ransack Gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) which basically does pretty much what i want.

The only thing is that it's not parsed as a logical expression but the query is constructed out of a nested form. (see their [Advanced Demo](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search) to try it out)

Hope this helps!